# Executing signal handlers at known points

Tags: c, linux, signals

What I want to do is to prevent signals from interrupting my application. At known points, for  example, before making a system call, I will check for pending signals and call their handlers. In other words, I want to defer signal handling to known points in the code.

Any idea how this can be done? Can this be done in user-space or kernel modification will be required?

Answer (score 1):

sigprocmask: http://resin.csoft.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?section=2&topic=sigprocmask

Comment: It says the signals can be blocked through this, but i'm interested in defering signal handling, and not completely blocking the signals. Can this be achieved with sigprocmask?

Comment: the signals are blocked not ignored, so pending signal handlers will run when you unblock, see http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/all-about-linux-signals?page=6

Comment: Note that modern library code should use `pthread_sigmask` rather than `sigprocmask`. Their specifications are nearly identical except that `pthread_sigmask` returns the error code (if an error happens, which won't happen anyway...) rather than setting `errno` and it's thread-safe. Use of `sigprocmask` in a threaded program is undefined so it's not a good idea to use it in library code that might get used in a threaded program - though in practice all real-world implementations are probably safe.

Comment: Can I check for a pending signal and execute it immediately? For example, through a system call, check if signal is pending and execute the signal handler.